# When trying to get the native element from xamarin forms view GetNativeElement() is returning null

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

So I'm passing a Xamarin forms View as parameter to the dependency service in UWP to take a screen capture of the passed View.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<byte[]> CaptureView(View view)
        {
            if (Platform.GetRenderer(view) == null)
            {
                Platform.SetRenderer(view, Platform.CreateRenderer(view));
            }
            var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(view);
            var nativeView = renderer?.GetNativeElement();
            if(nativeView == null)
            {
                renderer?.SetElement(view);
                nativeView = renderer?.GetNativeElement();
            }
            return await ReturnStream(nativeView);
        }



private async Task<byte[]> ReturnStream(UIElement content)
        {
            var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(content);
            var pixelpuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
            var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
            IRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
            encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, logicalDpi, logicalDpi, pixelpuffer.ToArray());
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
            byte[] resultingBuffer = new byte[stream.Size];
            await stream.ReadAsync(resultingBuffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)resultingBuffer.Length, InputStreamOptions.None);
            return resultingBuffer;
        }
```

I'm getting nativeView as null everytime in the CaptureView even if I have view in it and renderer is not null.

I'm trying to capture the view and return its image as a byte[] which I'll later convert to imagesource and place it in view.

Comment: I'm afraid I could not reproduce your problem, and I could not make a complete  sample  with above code, could you please share mini demo for us?

Comment: When I directly give view as a new Label it fails at renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(content); throwing value does not fall with in range. Seems like issue with the type of view. Is there any restrictions on which kind of the type of View to send?

Comment: Yep, there are many restrictions on RenderAsync method. please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap#xaml-visuals-and-rendertargetbitmap-capture-capabilities).